# Weired Behavior of my contract

Tags: solidity, blockchain, ether, dapps

As you can see my code of contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

contract GeoSpatialData{

    uint public SpatialDataCount = 0;
    
    struct GeoData{
        uint id;
        address owner_address;
        string data_name;
        string data_year;
        string data_description;
        string data_img_url;
        
        string data_category;
        string data_published_date;
    }

    GeoData[] public geoDatas;

    mapping (uint => GeoData) public geodatas;
    // write function
    function createData(string memory _data_name,address _owner_address,string memory _data_year,string memory  _data_description,string memory _data_image_url,string memory _data_published_date,string memory _data_category,uint _id ) public{
        SpatialDataCount++;
        uint used_id = SpatialDataCount+_id;
        geoDatas.push(GeoData({id: used_id,owner_address:_owner_address,data_name:_data_name,data_year:_data_year,data_description:_data_description,data_img_url:_data_image_url,data_category:_data_category,data_published_date:_data_published_date}));
        
    }
    // read all data  function
    // function fetchAlldata() public view returns(GeoData[] memory){
    //     GeoData[] memory geodatas
    //         return GeoData;
    // }

    // read single data function 
    // function readSingle() public{

    // }

}
```

`uint public SpatialDataCount = 0;`

i have declare this part as an integer but when i try to acces this comtract using the truffle consolse
[image]
This is what i get i am supposed to get only one integer please help today is my deadline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an object called big number. You could check it [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bn.js). If you want to convert it to just number, you could do this

```js
value = await x.SpatialDataCount()
value.toNumber()
```

But, be careful because maximum size of number that can be converted is 53 bits. If you just want to show it and not do any calculation, you could convert it to string use this

```js
value = await x.SpatialDataCount()
value.toString()
```

Comment: `x.SpatialDataCount().toNumber()
Uncaught TypeError: x.SpatialDataCount(...).toNumber is not a function
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>` This is the error i am getting

Comment: I edited the answer. Please try it again